# Shouldn't this HTML run correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events

I used editor.cloxy.net to program this (more about that site on my profile) but I cleaned it up to make it easier to read. I've been interested in HTML/CSS/JavaScript for about a year, but it is still pretty hard to make a simple program. I recently learned about key codes and made the script down below, but it didn't work so I made an account and asked the question. The code doesn't return an error, but it doesn't do what I intended: moving left when the player presses the left key, moving right when the player presses the right key, and etc. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A test</title>
    <style>
         #a {
           position: absolute;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="a">thing</button> 
    <script>
     var x = a.style.left
     var y = a.style.top
     document.onkeydown = function(e) {
         switch (e.keyCode) {
             case 37: //left
                 x -= 10
                 a.style.left = x + "px";
                 break;
             case 38: //up
                 y -= 10
                 a.style.top = y + "px";
                 break;
             case 39: //right
                 x += 10
                 a.style.left = x + "px";
                 break;
             case 40: //down
                 y += 10
                 a.style.top = y + "px";
                 break;
         }
       };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am hoping for a helpful answer, like I see on other questions. Please try and help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)/initialize your `x` and `y` values:

```js
var x = parseInt(a.style.left) || 0;
var y = parseInt(a.style.top) || 0;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: //left
      x -= 10
      a.style.left = x + "px";
      break;
    case 38: //up
      y -= 10
      a.style.top = y + "px";
      break;
    case 39: //right
      x += 10
      a.style.left = x + "px";
      break;
    case 40: //down
      y += 10
      a.style.top = y + "px";
      break;
  }
};
```

```css
#a {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button id="a">thing</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have no idea what "parse" or "parsing" means to be honest, but it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = a.style.left
var y = a.style.top
```

In this your variables x and y are of type string (numeric string). To convert numeric string to a number we have to use parseInt() function.

I hope now it is clear to you :)